# ADO API with TFS is deleting the URL project and returning an error

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm currently using [this ADO API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get test results. The Uri has the following structure:

"https://server.com:1234/tfs/Collection/Project"

The service endpoint is:

"_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?api-version=6.0"

Where I replace runId and testCaseResultId with the needed information.

Now, my request is failing with a 404 error, and when I check the url I see that the Project from my URI has been deleted. Is this normal behavior?

If I add one last "/" after the URI, I get a bad request error.

Comment: How are you calling the API? Update your question to include the code. Also, if this is on-prem TFS (or Azure DevOps Server), *what version*? API v6 may not be available in the version you're using.

Comment: I'm using TFS Version Dev17.M153.2, code works for API calls when the API version is 1.0, but isn't working when the api version is 6.0.

Comment: Right, because that's Azure DevOps Server 2019, which doesn't support the v6 APIs. It supports v5 APIs. Look closely at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The rest api version supported for Azure DevOps Server 2019 is v5.0. Please change your service endpoint to use 5.0 version `api-version=5.0`

You can click the Version dropdown list in the document to select correct api version. See below:

[image]